# (Serverless Framework Module) wait for promise to resolve before return statement

Tags: ecmascript-6, bluebird, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

Is it possible for a Serverless Framework module to wait for the "resolve" of a promise before returning?

I'm aware that promises themselves can't do that, but different frameworks/libraries ([express](http://expressjs.com/starter/basic-routing.html), [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support), [hapijs](http://hapijs.com/tutorials#adding-routes), etc.) solve this by having a method that defines when to return. I need something like this:

```
let http = require('http'),
    Promise = require('bluebird');

let action = (done) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http
      .get('http://domain.com', resolve.bind({}, 'all good!'))
      .on('error', reject.bind({}, 'all wrong!'));
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Result', response);
    return done(response);  // <----------- I wan't to see this as the response
                            //              of the lambda function
  });
};

module.exports.run = (event, context, cb) => cb(null, action(done));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, promises don't do that. It's impossible to read from the future, and don't want to (cannot) block. Your action is still asynchronous.

But given that your export takes a callback anyway, you can simply invoke that asynchronously:

```
module.exports.run = (event, context, cb) => {
    action().then(res => cb(null, res), err=>cb(err));
};
```

It would be better though of course if you just returned the promise.

Comment: Please give and example of returning a promise. thanks

Comment: @elliotrock `module.exports.run = (event, context) => action();`, so that after importing you'd do `run(…).then(…)` instead of passing a callback

Comment: Interesting I have use deferred Promises and in the handler ``return yourPromise.then(nextPromise).then(function(result){ cb(returnHttpFormattedResponse) } })``

Comment: Yes, better avoid that pattern. Users of your function want to use promises, not callbacks.